# How do I check if a corresponding checkbox is checked so that when I re-enable the one that is clicked, certain ones are enabled?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to re-enable the appropriate checkboxes depending on which one is clicked. My structure setup is 3x checkboxes for each slate. The idea is, if the users checks 1 of the 3 checkboxes in a slate, the remaining two in that slate will disable, while the corresponding checkboxes in the other slates that match the ID # will disable as well.

**What's working Example**

In the first picture, if you click "checkbox 1" in the first slate, checkbox 2 and 3 will disable along with every "checkbox 1" in the remaining slates. *That's intended.*

In the second picture, if you click "checkbox 2" in the second slate, the remaining checkbox 3 on that slate and every "checkbox 2" on the other slates are disabled. *That's intended.*

In the third picture, if you click "checkbox 3" in the third slate, the remaining checkboxes are disabled. *That's intended.*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Everything described above is working as intended as I want the user to select which order the slate appears based on the left middle right checkboxes.

**What's NOT working Example**

In the picture below, you'll see that when you uncheck the third box on the third slate, it unchecks everything on that slate and along with the corresponding "checkboxes" for that ID. It should look like example #2 above when unchecked.

[image]

The checkboxes will always have an ID of: *chkbx1, *chkbx2 and *chkbx3. In the end there will also be more than 4 slates. I'm hoping someone could help me finish this jQuery puzzle. Or nudge me in the right direction.

Below is an example of my current code along with a JSfiddle example.

```
   <div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
        Slate Order
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx3">
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
  
  <div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
        Slate Order
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx3">
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
  
  <div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
        Slate Order
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx3">
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
  
  <div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
        Slate Order
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="onebulletchkbx1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="onebulletchkbx2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="onebulletchkbx3">
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>

$('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx1]').on('click change', function() {
    
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx1]').prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).siblings().prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
            $('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx1]').prop('disabled', false);
            $(this).siblings().prop('disabled', false);         
            }
        }); 
    
$('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx2]').on('click change', function() { 

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx2]').prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).siblings().prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
            $('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx2]').prop('disabled', false);
            $(this).siblings().prop('disabled', false);         
            }
        });
        
$('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx3]').on('click change', function() {
    
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx3]').prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).siblings().prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
            $('input:checkbox[id*=chkbx3]').prop('disabled', false);
            $(this).siblings().prop('disabled', false);         
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3jrvhuna/

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons? They automatically uncheck the other buttons in the same group.

Comment: I did test using radio buttons but the problem with that is it allows the user to select slot 1 more than once. Or any of the 3 slots,

Comment: Radio buttons only solve part of the problem, a single choice within each "Slate Order" group. You'll need JS to deal with the conflict between groups in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

This could be reduced to a single function. You were litening for `'change click'` - that is 2 events, and as such your functions were firing twice. That could cause issues. Also, instead of using ids to identify and act upon, use relative paths. From the element that was clicked, find the parent enclosure and affect all checkboxes within.

```js
$('.singleslate-checkboxes [type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).closest('.singleslate-checkboxes').find(`input[type=checkbox]:not(#${$(this).attr('id')})`).prop('disabled', true);
  else $(this).closest('.singleslate-checkboxes').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
  Slate Order
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx3">
  <br />
  <br />
</div>

<div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
  Slate Order
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx3">
  <br />
  <br />
</div>

<div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
  Slate Order
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx3">
  <br />
  <br />
</div>

<div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
  Slate Order
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="onebulletchkbx1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="onebulletchkbx2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="onebulletchkbx3">
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the other checkboxes within the same parent `.singleslate-checkboxes` and use `not(this)` to exclude the current one and use `this.checked` boolean to enable/disable.

As mentioned in comments it would make more sense to use radio groups for this UI

```js
$('.singleslate-checkboxes :checkbox').on('change', function(e){
       $(this).closest('.singleslate-checkboxes')
               .find(':checkbox')
               .not(this)
               .prop('disabled', this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
        Slate Order
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="fourbulletchkbx3">
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
  
  <div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
        Slate Order
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="threebulletchkbx3">
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
  
  <div class="singleslate-checkboxes">
        Slate Order
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="twobulletchkbx3">
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it isn't disabling the corresponding checkboxes. It is only disabling the siblings in each group which is correct.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? If not it's not clear what expected behavior is supposed to be

Comment: If you look at the JSFiddle example I linked, you can test out what I have. Check a box, the siblings become disabled. Along with the correspond # on the remaining slates. If you select more than one check box, it still works until you uncheck it. It re-enables everything in the siblings along with the corresponding # which is the problem. How do I only re-enable the correct ones?

Comment: OK. [New fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pz24aw30/). Can probably be streamlined a bit more but don't have time right now

Comment: Thank you for the new fiddle. It is definitely paired down and streamlined code. Although, its operating correctly when the user selects a checkbox, it's re-enabling the incorrect boxes when the user unchecks.

Comment: Looking at it closer, it looks like the code just needs to check if a checkbox within each slate group isChecked, then ignore the re-enabling of any them in that group while only re-enabling the rest of them. .